# How to open a Glade-created window and wait for it to close, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gtk, glade

I want to make my own window, using Glade (3.14.2).

At a certain point in my program, I want to
1) Put up the window and let the user do stuff
2) Wait for it to close
3) Get values from the window object
4) Continue on in my code

So basically, I want to treat the window like a modal dialog - but one that I write and control.

I've tried for a few hours. The window appears just fine, as designed in Glade. The user can interact with it.

When the window closes, code that's been connected with signal_connect('destroy') executes.

But the code that invoked the window's show() method... does not continue executing after the window closes.

```
class GrammarNodeEditor
  #this makes the class visual:
  include GladeGUI

  def initialize(raw_node = nil, &close_block)
    @raw_node = raw_node || {type: :Sequence, data: []}
    @original_data = @raw_node[:data]
    @close_block = close_block
  end


  def show
    puts "GNE Window Opening"
    load_glade(__FILE__)
    @builder["window1"].title = "Edit/Create Grammar Node"
    @builder["window1"].signal_connect('destroy') {|*args|
      @close_block.call(self)
      puts "GNE WINDOW DESTROY"
    }
    show_window()
    puts "Done showing window"
  end
```

Here is how I invoke it:

```
  rhs_editor = GrammarNodeEditor.new {|obj|
    puts "In closeblck, obj is #{obj.inspect}"
    @rhs = obj.raw_node
  }
  puts "About to call show in GR:Init"
  rhs_editor.show
  puts "Back from calling show in GR:Init"
```

Here is the output:

```
About to call show in GR:Init
GNE Window Opening
In closeblck, obj is #<GrammarNodeEditor:0x7b82a88 @raw_node={:type=>:Sequence, :data=>[]}, [more junk here]>
GNE WINDOW DESTROY
```

The first two lines of output appear after I open the window. The 3rd and 4th appear when I close the window.

Note that "Done showing window" and "Back from calling show in GR:Init" are not printed at all.

Just to make this a little more interesting, I want to be able to do this from within code that puts up another window. My top-level window has a button to create a new Rule. The Rule must be initialized with a Node, and then the Rule must be edited. So first I need to put up a Node-definition window (as shown above) and then, when I have a Node defined, I want to put up a Rule window that uses that Node.

So I think I need to call this code within either the initialize() or the show() method of the GrammarRuleWindow class (another Glade-defined window).

Can someone explain why my puts's aren't being printed, and how to make the control flow go on through them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...So it turned out the problem was that I had created the window's .glade file directly in Glade, rather than using the VisualRuby IDE.

Creating the .glade in VR adds some stuff to the file that VR needs. Specifically, the file needs to contain the line

```
    <signal name="destroy" handler="destroy_window" swapped="no"/>
```

before the first <child...> tag.